# Where in your solution do you typically put your StructureMap Registry classes?

Tags: inversion-of-control, structuremap

Here's the current layout:

Solution:

- Core

  - Domain
  - Interfaces
- DataAccess

  - Providers
  - Session
- Service
- UI
- UnitTests
- IntegrationTests

I typically try to keep my core domain entities / POCOs as light as possible without very many external dependencies.. So I was thinking it might make sense to put it in the Service layer as it typically has a project reference to all of the layers.

I have noticed that in CodeCampServer they have actually created a separate project called DependencyResolution for their IoC configuration:

http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/source/browse/trunk#trunk/src/DependencyResolution

Thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536994/not-understanding-where-to-create-ioc-containers-in-system-architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOC configuration should be off to the side.  It doesn't necessarily need to be in a separate project, but it needs to be away from the application code.  We put it in another project in CodeCampServer to make 'off to the side' more real.  But in a current production app, we keep it in a separate namespace in our main project.  We consolidated projects to increase compile time.

Comment: I ran into circular reference problems when i put my Bootstrapper in a separate project. If my test projects and Web project reference the IoC project then it barfs! What's the solution here? For the moment i have IoC Init in the host web project and also it is Init'ed for the test projects too.

Comment: that's part of the point: don't reference your ioc project in your web project.  check out codecampserver. your ioc project shouldn't need a reference to your test project.